# C++ using reference object after destroying it

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, reference, destructor

I was trying some things with references and pointers, and I found something that I do not understand at all.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
     A() { cout << "con\n"; }
    ~A() { cout << "des\n"; }

    void f() { cout << "bla" << endl; }
};

A &createA()
{
    A *a = nullptr;

    {
        A b;
        a = &b;
        cout << *&a << endl;
    }

    return *a;
}

int main()
{
    A &b(createA());
    cout << &b << endl;

    b.f();

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
con
des
0058FE0B
0058FE0B
bla
Press any key to continue . . .
```

As you can see the member function f() still gets called, even after the object itself has been destroyed. Why? I thought there should be some error, but the function f() does get called and it event does everything correctly, why?

Comment: *undefined behavior* does not guarantee errors or crashes

Comment: Well *Undefined Behavior* means what will happen can be anything even things that apparently look something reasonable. That code is wrong, anything it can produce doesn't have to be considered.

Comment: OP should definitely read the accepted answer in the linked duplicate - it's a lovely analogy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is undefined behaviour, plain and simple.

The compiler is not required to warn you when you engage in UB, but it *is* allowed to assume you won't do that and if you do it anyway you have no guarantees about what will happen. The program is simply invalid and *anything* could happen.

Answer (score 2):

Compiler warnings are pretty self-explanatory here:

```
main.cpp: In function 'A& createA()':
main.cpp:24:13: warning: function may return address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
     return *a;
             ^
main.cpp:19:11: note: declared here
         A b;
           ^
```